# set image on a button in android?

Tags: android, button

i have been trying to set a image on a button using the following code but it doesn't seem to work...i think what i am doing wrong is the path of the image i am using but i tried different paths and it wont work...i have copied my image to the drawable folder in res folder...what am i doing wrong here??

```
final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02) ;
 Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/finalarrow1");
  next.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why not use

```
final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
next.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.finalarrow1);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the "Image Button" it's better for you ,,, and the code like this :

```
final ImageButton next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button02) ;
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/finalarrow1");
next.enter.setImageDrawable(d);
```