# Set icon on button center position through programatically

Tags: android, button, icons

[image]

I want to set icon on button on center place through programatically as the above diagram please any one help me...

Comment: What does the documentation for the Button class say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Change a Button's Icon Programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250923/how-to-change-a-buttons-icon-programmatically)

Comment: i dont know i am a new android

Comment: who is discourage my question if you dont know the answer just read and go away...

Comment: possible duplicate of [set image on a button in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709009/set-image-on-a-button-in-android)

Comment: i want to set icon in center position

Comment: Who is discourage my answer that person tell the answer now.Those who are all give the stupid link..first you understand what i want and then encourage or discourage my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May This helps you..

Set background image for button which is in Drawable folder then use below code:

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
```

**OR**

```
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
```

**Or use:** `setCompoundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds().`

Look More Regarding `setCompoundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds()` in its documentation : [CLICK HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

**Edit:**

**Try this way:** `setCompoundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawables.minus,0,0,0);`

Add this line in XML: `android:paddingLeft="100dp"`

Comment: sorry i want to set the icon center of button

Comment: Read the documentation of `setCompoundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds()` it will help you..

Comment: i read it but which defined only set icon left,right,bottom and top only if you know please tell me...

Comment: You have to specify integer values in that method where you want to set the image..

Comment: welcome satheesh.. and if my answer helped you then vote it buddy...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33244/discussion-between-satheesh-and-bhavin-nattar)